# MVC 4 - hand over changed value from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If a view is ment to allow editing of only one property but all other properties are being displayed (DisplayFor, non-editable) as well, **what is a good way to design the handing-over of changed value to the controller?**

Right now I have  hidden-input-fields for all properties that are displayed with DisplayFor and the controller gets the full object passed.

This is pretty much ineffecient and I know it would suffice to post only the ID of that object and the changed value.

The user can input the value to be changed like this:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Verkaufspreis)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Verkaufspreis)
```

I could pass the ID of the object like this

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ID })
```

But how would I pass the value that was changed? Thank you for your input.

Comment: do you know the value that supose to change

Comment: If you intend to notify a controller without doing an actual post request then you must use ajax.

Comment: @COLD TOLD: Yes I know the value, it's a little Stock Trading game and the action is "Sell a stock", the user has to input the price.

Comment: @Travis J, I've got no problem with a full post, but I do not know how the signature of the controller would have to look like.. If I had a hidden field for the ID and the EditorFor-Field for the value to be changed then both values would be in the post, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to get a value and you do not want to return the model knowing the name of the value you can use FormCollection

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult (FormCollectio collection)
{

    string Verkaufspreis1=collection["Verkaufspreis"].ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

MVC allows all kinds of binding, for instance you could go

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult (int ID, String Verkaufspreis)
//Have to be the same propery name as your model
{

    //Get original object with the ID
    //change the "Sell of Stock" field
}
```

This would dynamically pass the ID and Verkaufspreis as parameters.

This would allow you to only have the ID and the value needing to be changed, as you would be getting the rest from your database(or wherever) on postback, only updating the value that is necessary.

You could do the entire model as a parameter, although this would mean you would have alot of empty values if you're not passing them to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting a lot of hidden inputs in your form, you can do this.

Simply post the changed values and the id to the action method. Read the full entity from your data source and update the new values and save it back.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(CustomerViewModel model)
{
   Customer customer=repositary.GetCustomerFromID(model.ID)
   customer.DisplayName=model.DisplayName;
   repositary.SaveCustomer(customer);
   return RedirectToAction("ProfileUpdated");
}
```

In this case, you need to post only the `ID` and `DisplayName` properties from the form

```
@model CustomerViewModel
<h2>Update Customer details</h2>
@using(Html.Beginform())
{
  Display Name : @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.DisplayName)
  @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ID)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```